# Implication of Theorem on 'Empirical Bayes optimality' (Morris 1983)

Tags: bayesian, estimation, exponential-family

My question is about Theorem 1 from Morris 1983; Parametric Empirical Bayes Inference (http://www.jstor.org/stable/2287098?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

> Suppose Y has a univariate natural exponential familiy with quadratic variance function, and the mean $\theta$ of Y is to be estimated with quadratic loss $ L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = (\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2 $. In the class of all priors $ \Pi $ having mean $\mu$ and variance $A$, the conjugate prior $\pi_0$
>   is ''empirical bayes minimax''. That is if $ t_{\pi}(Y) = E_{\pi}(\theta \vert Y)$ then for all $\pi \in \Pi: \quad r(\pi, t_{\pi}) < r(\pi, t_{\pi_0})  = r_0 = r(\pi_0, t_{\pi_0}) < r(\pi_0, t_{\pi})$

Where $t$ is an estimator, $r(\pi, t) = E_\pi E_\theta[L(\theta, t(Y))]$, and $r_0 = r(\pi_0, t_{\pi_0}).$
$E_\pi, E_\theta$ denote the expectation w.r.t. to the distribution of $\theta$ and w.r.t. the conditional distribution of $Y$ given a realization of $\theta$. (The notation doesn't differ for the random variable $\theta$ and it's realization, but that's on Morris!)

Am I right in assuming that the theorem justifies using the conjugate prior,
once the decision for quadratic loss and the first two moments of the prior has been made?

Since quadratic loss is somehow standard and the first two moments in empirical bayes are usually the maximum likelihood estimates one would then stick to the theorem (if the distribution of $Y$ allows it's application)
and always chose conjugate priors in the empirical bayes setting.